# Is there any argument which to find real solutions of $x^{2n+1}+x+C=0$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For the case $n=1$ i.e $x^3+x+C=0$, there exists well known argument which to find real solution.

Let $x=u+v$, then $$0=x^3+x+C=(u+v)^3+u+v+C=u^3+v^3+C+(3uv+1)(u+v)$$
We want to find real $u,v$ such that $$u^3+v^3=-C, 3uv+1=0;\ \ u^3v^3=-\frac{1}{27}$$
Therefore $u^3,v^3$ is root of
$$y^2+Cy-\frac{1}{27}=0$$
Because of this we can get
$$u^3=\frac{-C+\sqrt{C^2+\frac{4}{27}}}{2},\ \ v^3=\frac{-C-\sqrt{C^2+\frac{4}{27}}}{2}$$
Because we want to find real solution, we only consider
$$u=\Big{(}\frac{-C+\sqrt{C^2+\frac{4}{27}}}{2}\Big{)}^{\frac{1}{3}},\ \ 
v=\Big{(}\frac{-C-\sqrt{C^2+\frac{4}{27}}}{2}\Big{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
Therefore we can get a real solution of $x^3+x+C=0$ s.t
$x=u+v=\Big{(}\frac{-C+\sqrt{C^2+\frac{4}{27}}}{2}\Big{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}+
\Big{(}\frac{-C-\sqrt{C^2+\frac{4}{27}}}{2}\Big{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}$
Generally, it is well-known facts that there isn't algebraic formula for equation with $degree\geq 5$. However, I wonder there exist any argument to find real solution for the special case $x^{2n+1}+x+C=0$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$.

Comment: $x^5+x+3$ has one real root, but it is not solvable by radicals. So we can only find a real solution numerically.

Comment: There are many posts solving $x^r+ax+b=0$ on this site